# tkinter home directory

Tags: python, operating-system, tkinter, tk-toolkit, home-directory

When calling the

```
 tkFileDialog.askopenfile()
```

method in tkinter, how do I set the default directory to the home directory of the user? Is there a way to do this independent of operating system, or is this something that the programmer has to deal with?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`os.path.expanduser('~')`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.expanduser) should expand it out for you on most OSs (windows,unix)...

In other words:

```
home = os.path.expanduser('~')
f = tkFileDialog.askopenfile(initialdir = home)
```